# WP7: scrobble song to last.fm

Tags: windows-phone-7, last.fm

I'd like to send a scrobble to last.fm, but don't know how to do this. I searched for the last.fm-API for C#. If I want to add it to the project it says it was not programmed for Windows Phone (of course). How can I still scrobble songs?

Answer (score 1):

Official Documentation

http://www.lastfm.ru/api/scrobbling

Just reading it now too...